# How to read files with Incremental file name in python?

Tags: python, list, file

I have multiple files with name like file00001, ....., file00111,.....file01555 and so on. I want to read them in increments in python. Whats the best way to do that? Initially I used the time of creation to read them in incremental order but unfortunately when I transferred these files to a different computer, time of creation of files and their names are no longer matching. so this code is not working. my code was something like this. some of the commands are software specific like pymol, cmd, but i assume rest of the code is quite general. I am sorry if the question is not properly asked but I am quite novice to python and programming is not my profession. It helps me getting my work done more efficiently thats why I am trying it.

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0Ca8.png)

Thanks
Dhiraj

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing the specific problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the site :)

Comment: Please include your code as text instead of as image, to make it copy/pastable and indexable by search engines.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do something to the file right away then move on:

```
def get_files():
    MAX_FILE_NUM = 100 #change
    fmat = lambda x: '{:05}'.format(x)

    for i in range(1, MAX_FILE_NUM + 1):
        path = 'file' + fmat(i)
        new_file = open(path, 'r')
        # Do something with the new_file object...

get_files()
```

If you want to be able to get one file at a time from the function:

```
def get_files():
    MAX_FILE_NUM = 100 #change
    fmat = lambda x: '{:05}'.format(x)
    for i in range(1, MAX_FILE_NUM + 1):
        path = 'file' + fmat(i)
        new_file = open(path, 'r')
        yield new_file

files = get_files()

print(next(files)) #<file object 1>
print(next(files)) #<file object 2>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this

```
import glob
path = ''#your path
files = glob.glob(path)
for name in files:
    with open(name) as f:
            for line in f:
                print(line.split())
```

You can read more about glob and see how to adjust it for your problem [glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html)